# Jquery: Dynamic adding <tag> depending on number of <div>

Tags: jquery, slider, javascript-framework

My question is how to add a list depending on the number of div. The result will be used for paging/navigation for a sliding banner

```
<div class="panel">
  <section>
    <h2>...</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </section>      
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <section>
    <h2>...</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </section>      
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <section>
    <h2>...</h2>
    <p>...</p>
  </section>      
</div>
```

The result should be something like this

```
<ul id="pagging">
  <li><a href="#">nav1</li>
  <li><a href="#">nav2</li>
  <li><a href="#">nav3</li>
</ul>
```

But for us we want it to be done in jquery. Our jquery will count the number of divs first, then dynamically add the LIs depending on the number of divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/yhufH/

Add/remove div's to test

Answer (score 2):

```
var divCount = $("div.panel").length;

for(var i=0;i<divCount;i++){
   $("ul#pagging").append($("<li/>").text("nav"+(i+1)));
}
```

Also, Paging only has one g.

http://jsfiddle.net/R8mxg/

Answer (score 0):

using JQuery.each

```
$("div.panel").each(function(idx){
      $("#pagging").append($("<li/>").text("nav"+(idx+1)));
})
```

note : inner code based on kingjiv's